# Match all except certain phrase

Tags: regex, regular-language

I found a numerous questions regard to "matching all except a single word in string". However, none of them do not work in case of phrase (two or more words combined). Suppose I have a string as in example ([RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/24457)). I want to match all possible combination of a single word + 10-digits number except of certain combination/phrase "nip + 10-digits number" (+ means a simple space). In my example I use `\bnip\s*\d{10}\b` to match "nip + 10-digits number" but I want to match all extept "nip + 10-digits number". `hello` should not be matched too because of lack of 10-digits number on the right side. Would be appreciated for any help.
**Example:**

```
   hello 
   alpha 1111111111 # should be matched
   allla 2322322321 # should be matched
   nip 5260305006 
   pin 5260305006 # should be matched
   nipp 5260305006 # should be matched
```

Comment: Like this? `\b(?!nip\b)\S+\s*\d{10}\b` https://regex101.com/r/dJwTrJ/1

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution I was looking for. I used ```\b(?!nip)\s*\d{10}\b``` but it didn't work. Would you explain what do you ```\S+``` add for?

Comment: It matches 1 or more non whitespace chars before matching the optional whitespace chars. I have added it as an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use

```
 \b(?!nip\b)\S+\s*\d{10}\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b(?!nip\b)` A word boundary, assert what is directly to the right is not `nip` and a word boundary
- `\S+\s*` Match 1+ non whitespace chars followed by optional whitespace chars *(Or use `\w+` instead of `\S+` to match only word chars)*
- `\d{10}\b` Match 10 digits followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJwTrJ/1)

If you want to `want to match all possible combination of a single word + 10-digits` and  don't want to match `nip + 10-digits number" (+ means a simple space)` you can exclude that from the match including the space and the 10 digits.

**Note** that this does match `nip5260305006` as there is no space in between.

```
\b(?!nip \d{10}\b)\S+\s*\d{10}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MFYJ8D/1)